# how to change UI Button width and height dynamically with respect to image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to change UIButton width and height dynamically with respect to image in ios?

```
[[btn_dynamic imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
//    btn_dynamic.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
//    btn_dynamic.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
//[btn_dynamic setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

I tried in these area but not working

Comment: how do you want your button's position changed when its size is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    float x=0;

    for(int i = 100; i < 110; i++)
     {
         btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];

         UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Round_Rect4.png"];

        [btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        titleString = [titleArray objectAtIndex:i-100];  // get button title

       CGSize fontSize = [titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];

        CGRect currentFrame = btn.frame;

        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(x, currentFrame.origin.y, fontSize.width + 22.0, fontSize.height + 12.0);

       [btn setFrame:buttonFrame];

        x = x + fontSize.width + 35.0;

        [btn setTitle:titleString forState: UIControlStateNormal];

        [btn setTag:i];

        [self.view addSubview:btn];
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Get the size of image

 UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnImage"];

 CGSize buttonSize = CGSizeMake(buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

 buttonInstance = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

 [buttonInstance setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Set the frame of button using image size

 [buttonInstance setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height)];
```

Comment: I would like to load list of buttons render from service and add to the view.All buttons are load with different height and width different cordinates could you please help me....

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom button as below

```
 UIButton *btnDynamic = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnDynamic setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It simply create a custom button as per image..

Hope it helps...!

Comment: This code will not take button frame automatically. It will take 0 width and 0 height. Please posting the code only if you are fully sure else please test it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to touch button frame and want to set image that do not look stretchy. Go with the code below

```
btn_dynamic.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

If you want to set button width and height, you need to set the button size according to the image size.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
CGRect btnFrame = btn_dynamic.frame;
btnFrame.size.width = image.size.width;
btnFrame.size.height = image.size.height;
[btn_dynamic setFrame:btnFrame];
```

If you want to maintain the ratio as the image could be larger than the view

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
CGRect btnFrame = btn_dynamic.frame;
btnFrame.size.width = 100; // lets the button width is 100 or set according to the need.
btnFrame.size.height = (btnFrame.size.width*image.size.height)/image.size.width;
[btn_dynamic setFrame:btnFrame];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to change the button size.

```
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
CGRect rectButton = button.frame;

rectButton.size = imageSize
button.frame = rectButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solutions

```
TestButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);

[TestButton sizeToFit];

float width  =   TestButton.frame.size.width + 20;

TestButton.frame = CGRectMake(TestButton.frame.origin.x, 
TestButton.frame.origin.y, width, 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

who ever looking for an auto layout solution what i did was i kept a temp uilable with text color clear color, at bottom of the uibutton and set the auto layouts as,
1. uibutton left = tmp uilabel left
2. uibutton right = tmp uilabel right

so by setting tmp label text, the label will auto adjust its width according to the text and since the label and button have equal left and right the button will also automatically expand its width.

Hope this helps..